# make a lookup between IPv6 subnet and IPv6 address with KUSTO

Tags: ipv6, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

KUSTO have the ipv4_lookup plugin function to match between IPv4 subnets and addresses (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin). There is no similar function for IPv6, is there another way to get the same results but for IPv6?

Comment: In almost all cases, the IPv6 network should be `/64`, so it is easy to get the network, just use the first four field and end in `::`. The two exceptions would be `/127` and `/128`, and those are even easier..

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin. But I took the subnets from MAXMIND and they give subnets in the range from /45 to /64 and everything between. So I can not just put zeros in the last 2 bytes, I need a more accurate way to deal with the problem.

Comment: Anything shorter than `/64` is a prefix to be delegated and divided into `/64` networks. For example, the longest prefix that can be advertised on the public Internet is `/48`, so that is a common prefix length to assign to a site, and it can be broken into 65,536 `/64` networks. A prefix like a `/45` as you say will have eight times as many `/64` networks as a `/48` prefix. To figure out how many `/64` networks are in a prefix, simply subtract the prefix length from `64` and raise `2` to that power, e.g. `2^(64-45) = 2^19 = 524,288` standard `/64` networks in a `/45` prefix.

Comment: [This answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499) explains the problems with using network sizes other than `/64`.